# GET in TCP connection with C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a program in Delphi with make a request to TCP. As I am beginning to work with C#, I try to translate it. Follow the code in Pascal, but for instance I don't know how to make it work in C#:

```
var
  s:shortstring;
  CR,LF:char;
  l:integer;
  buffer:TIdBytes;
  resp: TStringStream;
  ouvert:integer;
begin
  TCP:=TIdTCPClient.Create;
  CR:=chr(13);
  LF:=chr(10);
  TCP.Host:='192.168.52.203';
  TCP.Port:=80;
  TCP.Connect;
  if TCP.Connected then
  begin
    s:='GET /state.xml?noReply=0 HTTP/1.1'+CR+LF+'Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ=='+CR+LF+CR+LF;
    l:=Length(s);
    SetLength(buffer,l);
    Move(s[1],Buffer[0],l);
    TCP.IOHandler.Write(Buffer,l);
    resp := TStringStream.Create;
    TCP.IOHandler.ReadStream(resp,185);
    resp.Position:=0;
//    memoGet.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp);
    resp.Position:=0;
    s:=Resp.ReadString(185);
```

Thanks for your help.
Michel

Comment: Is there any reason you'd want to do this rather than using a tried-and-testing HTTP client?

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Do not "translate" code. Figure out what you want to do and then do it in the other language in that language's eco system - whatever that other language might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate it to C# via the TcpClient and NetworkStream usings from System.net.sockets namespace.

It may look like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var tcp = new TcpClient();
        var cr = "\r";
        var lf = "\n";
        var host = "192.168.52.203";
        var port = 80;
        tcp.Connect(host, port);
        if (tcp.Connected)
        {
            var request = "GET /state.xml?noReply=0 HTTP/1.1" + cr + lf + "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==" + cr + lf + cr + lf;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
            var stream = tcp.GetStream();
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly would be the benefit over using `HttpClient` ?

Comment: It was never stated that it must be "HTTPS". It is just a brief example so he/she can have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it's working fine. I have now a small program written in C# able to tell me if the roof of my automatic astronomical observatory is open.
Michel

Comment: Glad it works, if you would please mark my answer so people know it works, thank you!